# How to get a value in one mongodb collection and use that value to update another document in another collection order & inventory system

Tags: arrays, mongodb, multidimensional-array, pymongo

Hello I have been stuck for weeks trying to figure how to create a order & inventory system for a project I am working on. I don't know how to properly ask this but my  problem is when a user adds items to their cart >  I store the order details in a orders collection in mongodb > I then need to figure out how to subtract the quantity of the items in a customers order from my inventory collection. How can I do this with mongodb, Python
    This is the document created when a customer places an order

```
{
"_id": "5eca94b4f56331fd9eade681",
"ordernumber": 343,
"order": {
  "order_details": [
    {
      "customer_info": [
        {
          "first_name": "John",
          "last_name": "Doe",
          "email": "email@email.com"
        }
      ],
      "shipping_details": [
        {
          "shipping_address": "Test Address",
          "shipping_zip": "12345",
          "shippingl_city": "Test city",
          "shipping_country": "USA"
        }
      ],
      "products_ordered": [
        {
          "variant_id": "a",
          "product_name": "red shirt",
          "price": 30,
          "quantity": 2,
          "image": "imageurl",
          "size": "Small"
        },
        {
          "variant_id": "f",
          "product_name": "Blue Jeans",
          "price": 20,
          "quantity": 3,
          "image": "imageurl",
          "size": "Large"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

}

These are the products  in my inventory collection I want inventory order quantity subtracted  by the quantity a customer purchased

```
  {
    "_id": "5eca0ff4898b8f30a9fee5e5",
    "product_id": 1,
    "product_name": "red shirt",
    "category": "shirts",
    "price": 30,
    "status": "instock",
    "description": "nice red shirt",
    "alt": "string",
    "images": [
      "imageUrl1",
      "imageUrl2"
    ],
    "variants": [
      {
        "Small": [
          {
            "variant_id": "a",
            "inventory": 30
          }
        ],
        "Medium": [
          {
            "variant_id": "b",
            "inventory": 10
          }
        ],
        "Large": [
          {
            "variant_id": "c",
            "inventory": 10
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }

{
    "_id": "5eca108f898b8f30a9fee5e6",
    "product_id": 2,
    "product_name": "blue jeans",
    "category": "jeans",
    "price": 20,
    "status": "instock",
    "description": "nice blue jeans",
    "alt": "string",
    "images": [
      "ImageURL"
    ],
    "variants": [
      {
        "Small": [
          {
            "variant_id": "d",
            "inventory": 100
          }
        ],
        "Medium": [
          {
            "variant_id": "e",
            "inventory": 150
          }
        ],
        "Large": [
          {
            "variant_id": "f",
            "inventory": 70
          }
        ] }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to do it along with the service which creates the order.

I would also like to suggest to refactor the db structure a bit as it would be harder to maintain this in a larger scale.

Because currently we would have to write something like

```
for ordered_product in products_ordered:
    query = { "product_name": ordered_product.get("product_name") }
    inventory_product = inventory_collection.find_one(query)
    product_id = inventory_product["_id"]
    existing_count = inventory_product["variants"][0][ordered_product.size][0]["inventory"]
    inventory_product["variants"][0][ordered_product["size"]][0]["inventory"] = existing_count - ordered_product["quantity"]
    inventory_collection.update_one({ "_id": product_id }, { "$set": inventory_product })
```

I have hardcoded the index values of the list. You could use filter() to filter out the variant and size you need.

This code definitely seems messy to me.
Of course you could refactor this code by splitting it into functions inside the model file itself, but I would suggest to refactor the db structure for better scalability.

May be you could move the variants to a seperate collection and use the product_id as a link. You have to think this through before getting on with the code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is messy because I am learning  mongodb while also building. Thank you I was able to follow your suggestions and I  now have it working with a much simpler schema thanks.